# Combine routes from multiple files in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

What is the best way to **combine** routes from **two** files so Express Router will handle them at the **same** level?  I'm thinking of something like this:

**Default Routes File**
This file would be generated and overwritten every time the generator runs:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    router      = express.Router(),
    custom      = require('./custom.routes');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
});
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
});
router.put('/', function (req, res) {
});

router.use('/', custom);

module.exports = router;
```

**Custom Routes File**
This file would only be generated the first time and would never be overwritten.

```
var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router();

router.post('/custom-method', function (req, res) {

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Parent Route File**
This file is generated and overwritten constantly.  It is responsible for providing the top level `api` route:

```
var express = require('express'),
    apiRouter  = express.Router();

var widgetRouter = require('./widget.routes');
apiRouter.use('/widgets', widgetRouter);

var sprocketRouter = require('./sprocket.routes');
apiRouter.use('/sprockets', sprocketRouter);

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

The obvious goal is to allow the developer to customize the routes and know his work will be safe even when the generator is run again.

Answer (score 8):

`router.use()` does not necessarily need to take you deeper in the tree. You could just add the following line before the exports of the first file.

```
router.use('/', require('./routes.custom.js'));
```

With this you can also remove the wrapper from the custom file.

Comment: Oh, yeeeeah!  Geesh!  I was overcomplicating it.